# Spring JPA repository doesn't return List of entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I try to get simple List of Rawtype entities with help of findBy method in the **myMethod**. But I get nothing - rawtypes doesn't contain any entity. Although **findAll** method works fine. Please tell we where is my mistake.

Rawtype.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rawtype")
public class Rawtype implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="rtid", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private int rtId;

    @Column(name="rtname", nullable = false)
    private String rtName;

    //getters and setters
```

RawtypeRepository.java

```
public interface RawtypeRepository extends JpaRepository<Rawtype, Integer> {
    List<Rawtype> findByRtName(String rtName);
}
```

RawtypeServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class RawtypeServiceImpl implements RawtypeService {
    @Autowired
    RawtypeRepository rawtypeRepository;

    public List<Rawtype> findAll() {
        return rawtypeRepository.findAll();
    }

    public myMethod(){
        List<Rawtype> rawtypes = rawtypeRepository.findByRtName("RawName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not write a test that adds an entity with rtName set to "RawName" then tries to findByRtName()?  BTW, I don't think it needs @Transactional, your operations are currently read-only.

Comment: @todd-w-crone Thank you for your answer. I'm going to add some CRUD methods in the RawtypeServiceImpl(). Consequently I will need in that annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try printing `rtName` of all the entities returned by `findAll()` method? May be there isn't any record with 'RawName' as `rtName`.

Also, you can enable `logging` for JPA to see the generated query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a mistake in importing data from Excel to MySql. This import added some non visual symbols like "\n". As the result findByRtName return wrong values.